# Multi-Graphing in R with Normal

Tags: r, graph, distribution

I was trying to graph an experimental data with a normal curve (for comparisons). I could graph one of the curves just fine, but the normal curve couldn't be plotted in properly, I could only see a line running down the screen. I get same result for dcauchy. The only curve which is plotted properly is the "pdf_cauchy" variable.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
plot(pdf_cauchy, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 4)
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 1), add = T, col = "blue", lwd = 4)
x <- seq(-5, 5, by = .001)
lines(dcauchy(x, 0, 1, FALSE), type = "l", col = "green", lwd = 4)
```

Here is the data in "pdf_cauchy"

```
c(0.00127277, 0.00132412, 0.0013786, 0.00143646, 0.00149797, 
0.00156345, 0.00163324, 0.00170772, 0.00178731, 0.00187247, 0.00196372, 
0.00206165, 0.00216691, 0.00228022, 0.00240241, 0.00253439, 0.0026772, 
0.00283202, 0.00300018, 0.00318319, 0.00338278, 0.0036009, 0.0038398, 
0.00410205, 0.00439061, 0.00470887, 0.00506072, 0.00545067, 0.00588391, 
0.00636639, 0.00690497, 0.00750753, 0.00818301, 0.00894155, 0.00979444, 
0.010754, 0.0118334, 0.0130459, 0.0144036, 0.015916, 0.0175867, 
0.0194097, 0.0213637, 0.0234058, 0.0254655, 0.0274413, 0.0292036, 
0.0306076, 0.0315168, 0.0318319, 0.0315168, 0.0306076, 0.0292036, 
0.0274413, 0.0254655, 0.0234058, 0.0213637, 0.0194097, 0.0175867, 
0.015916, 0.0144036, 0.0130459, 0.0118334, 0.010754, 0.00979444, 
0.00894155, 0.00818301, 0.00750753, 0.00690497, 0.00636639, 0.00588391, 
0.00545067, 0.00506072, 0.00470887, 0.00439061, 0.00410205, 0.0038398, 
0.0036009, 0.00338278, 0.00318319, 0.00300018, 0.00283202, 0.0026772, 
0.00253439, 0.00240241, 0.00228022, 0.00216691, 0.00206165, 0.00196372, 
0.00187247, 0.00178731, 0.00170772, 0.00163324, 0.00156345, 0.00149797, 
0.00143646, 0.0013786, 0.00132412, 0.0012
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what your x-axis is in these graphs.  Your initial plot has no x-axis given and therefore just uses 1:100 for the 100 Cauchy values.  Now you add a normal curve to that starting at 0 and going to 100 with a mean of 0.  You're only going to get the right half of the curve and and extreme value at that.  With a mean of 50 and an sd of 25 you'll get something more reasonable and you could also do something similar with dcauchy.

You probably really need to put some x-values in your initial plot but I don't know what they'd be.  Did you want the placement to have the peak at 0?... some other value?  Only you know what the location and extent of the x-axis should be.

Comment: I wanted for the mean (center) to be around 0.

Comment: I had a feeling it could have been a problem with x domain, how could I change it so I'm only observing values from -5 to 5?

Comment: You make the x-value, just stick it into the first plot command.  I'd change it to `x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = length(pdf_cauchy))`.  That way it matches the length of your cauchy data.  That will partially fix up your first two graphing commands (except for the ylim) but you still need work on the third.

Comment: So would the dnorm and dcauchy be taking "length.out" as an argument?

Comment: No, the initial plot sets the plot space so set the limits of x and y you want for all of them to be in when you make thi initial plot.

Comment: I have answered my own question and showed a way to plot the 3 graphs. Now, my y-axis values are kind of screwed up. It is showing all the 3 y-axis together, so it looks really bad. Is there a way to just show values from say 0 to .5 on y-axis?

Comment: The ylim argument to plot will solve this, it takes a vector of two values c(0, 0.5) in your case. You should look at the help on plot and plot.default and look through the examples.  It's great that you answered your question, you'll remember it much better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to plot:

```
plot(x, dcauchy(x, 0, 1, FALSE), type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 4)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, pdf_cauchy, type = "l", col = "blue", lwd = 2)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, dnorm(x, 0, 1), type = "l", col = "green", lwd = 3)
```